# Liquibase: how to keep not-null-constraint and default value when running modifyDataType?

Tags: liquibase

What I've tried is to put the constraint and default value in the attribute newDataType, but all is ignored after the word `datetime`.

```xml
<modifyDataType tableName="my_table" columnName="my_column" newDataType="datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp() NOT NULL"/>
```

I also tried to solve this by adding the following line to the change set.

```xml
<addNotNullConstraint tableName="my_table" columnName="my_column" columnDataType="datetime" defaultNullValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
```

When I change `datetime` into `timestamp` all is working as expected.

"Fun" fact is that for older versions (Liquibase 3) when adding a space in front of `datetime` apparently a condition is not met and the stripping of the value of the attribute `newDateType` doesn't kicks in.

The version of Liquibase that I use is version: 4.26.0. The database on which the changesets are run at is MariaDB 11.3.2